# 403 response in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to write a spring boot application but when I try to test it by sending it POST requests it keeps returning a 403 response no matter the request. Even if I request an invalid link it will still respond with a 403 rather than a 404. I am currently using Spring version 3.1.3 but I have also tried going back to older versions like 2.7.15 to use some of the older features like '*WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*' and I still couldn't manage to fix it. I have also tried disabling csrf but that doesn't seem to work either.
Here are some of the files such as 'pom.xml', 'SecurityConfig.java', 'EmployeeController.java' and 'application.properties'.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>register</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>register</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
package register;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return  new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_myAuthority")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
        // ...

        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll())
                .build();
    }

/*
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest()
                .permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }

 */
}
```

EmployeeController.java

```
package register;


//import com.example.RegisterLogin.Dto.EmployeeDTO;
//import com.example.RegisterLogin.Dto.LoginDTO;
//import com.example.RegisterLogin.Service.EmployeeService;
//import com.example.RegisterLogin.response.LoginResponse;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
// @Secured("ROLE_myAuthority")
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @PostMapping(path = "/save")
    public String saveEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeDTO employeeDTO)
    {
        return employeeService.addEmployee(employeeDTO);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=register
server.port=8080

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbkms?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

#jpa vendor adapter configuration

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: Have you tried to add cors configuration yet ? together with disabled csrf.

Comment: You have 2 securityfilterchain, one that closes everything and one that opens everything. The one that closes everything has precedence.

Comment: @M.Deinum The first one should've been commented out as well. I fixed it but that did not resolve the issure. the POST request that I send to http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employee/save using PostMan still returns a 403.

Comment: @AndreiLisa Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: It is a post, yoiu didn't disable csrf which is required by default regardless if you have access rules that allow access to anyone. CSRF protection is not tied to access rules.

Comment: just decomment second `SecurityFilterChain` and comment third one, but instead of `.requestMatchers("/").permitAll()` use `.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()`

Comment: just second decomment, the first `filter` also leave it commented.

Comment: @AndreiLisa Thank you! It fixed the 403 error response! however it is now returning a 415 response. I suppose I must find a fix for that as well...

Comment: no problems, you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your FilterChain bean to:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest()
                .permitAll());
        return http.build();
}
```

Most probably you should use your 2nd commented out code piece instead to be:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .build();
    }
```

But yeah, in general either use CSRF strictly or disable it and keep your security more fine grained instead of just permitting all requests to go through.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're facing with Spring Security returning a 403 Forbidden error for all requests might be related to the way you've configured your security rules.

Ensure that your security rules in `SecurityConfig.java` are properly configured for your use case. The `SecurityFilterChain` and the `SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http)` configurations may conflict with each other. Try simplifying your security configuration to isolate the issue.

In your `SecurityConfig.java`, you have two `SecurityFilterChain` beans defined. Remove one of them to avoid conflicts. For instance, you can keep the `SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http)` bean and remove the other.

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    // ... (existing beans)

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_myAuthority")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
        // ...

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Make sure that the role name you're checking in `SecurityConfig.java` (`ROLE_myAuthority`) matches the actual role name assigned to users or endpoints. If it doesn't match, Spring Security won't grant access, resulting in a 403 error.

Also,  You can enable Spring Security debug logging to get more information about what's happening during authentication and authorization. Add the following to your `application.properties` file:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was because spring prefix the roles with ***SCOPE_*** but I was using in preauthorize annotation ***ROLE_ADMIN*** instaed of ***SCOPE_ROLE_ADMIN***,

Try to add this line in your application.props to see more info about the 403 error :

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```